# Character to date format conversion

Tags: r, date, as.date

```
x <- c("1-jan-60", "2-jan-89", "31-mar-89", "30-jul-93")
z <- as.Date(x, "%d-%b-%y")
z
"2060-01-01" "1989-01-02" "1989-03-31" "1993-07-30"
```

I converted character date into date format it is giving as wrong output.

the output should be

```
"1960-01-01" "1989-01-02" "1989-03-31" "1993-07-30"
```

Comment: Y2K problem revisited... ;-) How should the code know that you mean 1960 and not 2060? The latter is closer to the current date.

Comment: aahh , that is why `-69` gives `1969` and `-68` gives `2068`

Comment: `?strptime` explanation of the `%y` tag says "On input, values 00 to 68 are prefixed by 20 and 69 to 99 by 19"

Comment: @Sotos I didn't want to say that R always selects the closest year in such cases.  Ben Bolker has clarified how this is done. What I wanted to point out is that the date is ambiguous, and that it seems plausible that when a difference of about 50 years is involved it would be a good idea to specify the century.

Comment: http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html: `Internally, Date objects are stored as the number of days since January 1, 1970, using negative numbers for earlier dates.`

Comment: @RHertel, Yes I just did the math :)

Comment: @zyurnaidi : interesting fact, but irrelevant to the current question